# Java - Super.toString() method in base class?

Tags: java, tostring, super, base-class

My question is what is the reason to write Super.toString() in base class and what it returns and why ?

this is my code :

```
class Person    {
public String toString()    {
        return super.toString() /*+ "->" + "Person" + name + "------"*/;
        }
}
```

what is supposed to be return ? and thanks i m beginner in java

Comment: That depends what your base class is.

Comment: You would do that if the string representation of your class should incorporate the string representation of its supertype. Instead of duplicating the code in the superclass that prints the properties that your class inherits from it, you just call its `toString()`

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? I think that the best way to know what your code will return is to try to execute it ;)

Comment: @riccardo.cardin yes i run my code and i understand that if i use super.toString() in base class then it returns class name of that class and some code after '@' i don't know what that code is and when put same method in derived class at that time it displays name of base class and '@' and some code so now i understand that it returns class name of the class and if we use that in derived class it returns base class name i think i understand right ? just say what i said is right or wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class Person should extend parent class where you define method toString(), otherwise your parent class is class Object and the native method of this class is going to be used:

```
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

So, you will get a string that consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign @, and unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object
It's recommended that all classes (subclasses of class Object) override this method.

Answer (score 2):

`super` keyword is used to call parent class methods in case of inheritance.
Every class is the child of `Object` class in java and one of its non-final methods is `toString()`.
So`super.toString()` calls `Object`class method `toString()` .